# I want opposite results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables I want to display student without results

Student tables

```
Sname  snumber
A              1
B              2
C              3
G              4
```

And results table

```
Snumber  marks
1                 90
4                 60
```

I have the following code

```
Select student.sname from student
Join results
On student.snumber=results.snumber
```

Its showing students With results. I want student without results which is B and C

Comment: study about left join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
Select student.sname 
from student
LEFT Join results
    On student.snumber=results.snumber
WHERE results.snumber is null
```

If you want all the students then remove the where clause.

Answer (score 2):

After `LEFT JOIN` solution (@Jatin Patel), you can see `NOT EXISTS` one:

```
SELECT *
FROM Students S
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM results R WHERE S.snumber=R.snumber)
```